# can't deploy contract from web3 to geth node , Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3js, truffle, evm

I have web3 running in a Nodejs project.
I have used this genesis.json:

```
{
"config": {
    "chainId": 123456,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0
},
"alloc": {
    "0xa6B49C993142E**************************": {
        "balance": "120000000000000000000000"
    },
    "0xfd2041dcdc815**************************":{
        "balance": "120000000000000000000000"
    }
},
"difficulty": "0",
"gasLimit": "8000000"
```

}

I have geth init with the previous genesis file.
I have geth running on a remote instance.
here is the geth command:

```
sudo geth --port 3001 --networkid 123456 --nodiscover --datadir=./blkchain --maxpeers=0 --keystore ~/.ethereum/keystore --http --miner.etherbase 0xa6B49C9931************** --miner.threads 1 --http.port 8545 --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.corsdomain "*" --http.api "eth,net,web3,personal,miner" --ws --ws.port 8545 --ws.addr 0.0.0.0 --ws.api "eth,net,web3,personal,miner" --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock 0xa6B49C9931************** --syncmode fast
```

when trying to deploy a new contract from web3 (I have tried many versions of web3 including all stable versions), I got this error:
Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM,
TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError....

but on the other hand, the same contract in Truffle, I succeeded with migrating and also deploying the same contract.

Does anyone have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying on local network to test you contract you should consider using [ganache](http://trufflesuite.com/ganache/).
It has GUI and works great with truffle